# How to remove border while using vertical align property html

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<table width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#669999" border="10" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Nyala; font-size: 90px; color: #000;"><p><span class="font1">Name<br /></span>
        Name2</p></td>
        <td width="300" align="center" style="vertical-align:top" style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My Question:

When I DO NOT use the `style="vertical-align:top"` property, I am NOT getting a thin border around the second column. However, when I DO use this property, I don't know from where I get the border whereas I am using `border-width` property set to `0`.

I **don't** want to get any kind of border while using `vertical-align` property.

Comment: I have this thin border in both cases.

Comment: Please don't use the same attribute multiple times (your last `td` has two `style` attributes). Different browsers handle this differently, most ignore one of them, plus it's against the standard.

Comment: then how to use multiple "style" in a single td?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated the style attribute of html element td. You have to specify all different styles inside 1 attribute, separated by semi-colon.
Change

```
<td width="300" align="center" style="vertical-align:top" style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>
```

into

```
<td width="300" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>
```

Comment: it would be a good idea to advise using style sheets. cleaner and easier to update :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#669999" border="10" cellpadding="0"    cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
    <td style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Nyala; font-size: 90px; color: #000;"><p><span class="font1">Name<br /></span>
    Name2</p></td>
    <td width="300" align="center" style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px; vertical-align:top; "><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>
```

What I changed was `style="vertical-align:top" style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"`

I put it all in one style section and added semi colons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your quick fix : Remove the second style property, and move its content into the first one.

```
<td width="300" align="center" style="vertical-align:top; border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>
```

Note that you cannot have two properties with the same name in an HTML tag.